# Не работает fragment shared element transition

Tags: android, анимация, android-fragment

Я пытаюсь сделать переход с анимацией между двумя фрагментами. Написал пару "хелоуворлдов" - все работает. Но при написании аналогичного кода в приложении, анимации не происходит. Просто переключаются экраны.

Сначала я пришел к том, что все дело в том что для транзакции используется метод add(), но я нашел как это обойти. Но анимация все равно не работает. Пробовал setReorderingAllowed(true). Не помоглою. Пробовал добавлять флаг в главную тему приложения в style (windowContentTransitions). Про transition name в layouts не забыл. Совпадает все верно. Импорт использую support(Для фрагментво и транзакций). На стэке прочитал уже все возможные вопросы по этой теме.

Есть некоторые другие методы применяемые к транзакции(в дополнение к описанным в коде): hide(fragment), remove(fragment), fragment.pause(). Возможно что-то из этих методов аффектит на анимацию?

Пример рабочего "хелоуворлда":

```java
        val fragment = SecondFragment.newInstance("","")
        fragment.sharedElementEnterTransition = DetailsTransition()

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .setReorderingAllowed(true)
            .addSharedElement(view, "2")
            .detach(currentFragment!!)
            .add(R.id.content, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss()

        currentFragment = fragment
```

Приблизительный код моего приложения похож на то что выше, только в анимации я использую: ChangeBounds, ChangeTransform, duration = 15000

Анимация не происходит. Исключений не бросает

Answer (score 0):

Как сказано в [доке](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html), надо убедиться, чтобы добавляемые фрагменты вызвали метод **onCreate(Bundle)** до того как заменяемые фрагменты вызвали **onDestroy ()**, таким образом позволяя создать **shared view** и стартануть анимацию.

> Added fragments will have onCreate(Bundle) called before replaced
>   fragments have onDestroy() called, allowing the shared view to get
>   created and laid out before the transition starts.